# How to filter a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to filter out all `FALSE` entries in a dataframe I've created using the `mtcars` dataset. 
I have tried using `filter` function but I do not understand it, and I've tried `is.na` function but I couldn't get this to work.

Below is how I've created the dataframe

```
James_Test <- data.frame(rownames(mtcars), mtcars$mpg, mtcars$mpg > 15)
James_Test_names <- c("Model", "MPG", "MPG > 15")
colnames(James_Test) <- James_Test_names
head(James_Test, 7)

#               Model  MPG MPG > 15
# 1         Mazda RX4 21.0     TRUE
# 2     Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0     TRUE
# 3        Datsun 710 22.8     TRUE
# 4    Hornet 4 Drive 21.4     TRUE
# 5 Hornet Sportabout 18.7     TRUE
# 6           Valiant 18.1     TRUE
# 7        Duster 360 14.3    FALSE
```

I would like to be only left with the `TRUE` result and none of the `FALSE` entries.

Comment: `James_Test[James_Test$\`MPG > 15\`,]`

Comment: Perhaps this would help. It shows a subset based on an inequality and compares two most popular basic methods. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/why-is-better-than-subset

Comment: Alternatively: `James_Test <- data.frame(Model=row.names(mtcars)[mtcars$mpg>15], MPG=mtcars$mpg[mtcars$mpg>15], MPG_Over_15=TRUE)`

Comment: If you just want rows with MPG > 15, you theoretically don't even need the `MPG > 15` column. Using `dplyr` you can just do: `dplyr::filter(James_Test, MGP > 15)`. This will filter the data so it only shows rows there MPG is gr eater than 15.

Comment: Just use tidy verse. `James_Test %>% filter(`MPG > 15` == TRUE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From dplyr package:

```
filter(James_Test, `MPG > 15` == TRUE)
```